# Group by a formatted variable in PROC SQL

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

I am trying to group by custom formatted variable in PROC SQL, but so far have not found a solution. The log has no errors (like a [summary statistic error here](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Enterprise-Guide/Proc-SQL-Group-By-Formatted-Values/td-p/187278)) and all code is valid. Here's a simple example:

```
DATA have;
    INPUT value1;
    DATALINES;
1.22
0.99
0.22
4.00
9.99
;
RUN;

PROC FORMAT;
    value valuefmt
        low-.99="Below $1.00"
        1-5="$1-5.00"
        5-high="Above $5.00";
RUN;

DATA have;
    set have;
    FORMAT value1 valuefmt.;
RUN;

PROC SQL;
    SELECT count(*), value1 from have group by value1;
QUIT;
```

The PROC SQL returns the count grouped by the original value (value1), not the formatted value:

```
               value1
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
       1  Below $1.00
       1  Below $1.00
       1  $1-5.00    
       1  $1-5.00    
       1  Above $5.00
```

This functionality is allowed in SAS through FREQ or TABULATE. Example:

```
PROC TABULATE data=have;
    CLASS value1;
    TABLE value1;
RUN;

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
|                value1                |
|~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~|
|Below $1.00 |  $1-5.00   |Above $5.00 |
|~~~~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~~~~|
|     N      |     N      |     N      |
|~~~~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~~~~+~~~~~~~~~~~~|
|        2.00|        2.00|        1.00|
-~~~~~~~~~~~~-~~~~~~~~~~~~-~~~~~~~~~~~~-
```

Any ideas about how to do something similar with PROC SQL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way is to use the PUT() function in the GROUP BY clause.  You could just return the formatted value.

```
proc sql;
  select count(*) as N
       , put(value1,valuefmt.) as CharacterValue
  from have
  group by 2
  ;
quit;
```

Else you will need to add an aggregate function like MIN() if you want to return a value in the original type.  You will also need to re-apply the format.

```
proc sql;
  select count(*) as N
       , min(value1) as Formmatted format=valuefmt.
       , min(value1) as Raw
  from have
  group by put(value1,valuefmt.)
  ;
quit;
```

Results

```
   N   Formmatted       Raw
-------------------------------
   2  $1-5.00          1.22
   1  Above $5.00      9.99
   2  Below $1.00      0.22
```

Comment: What does `group by 2` do? The first statement works well, you could also use `group by calculated CharacterValue`. Thanks!

Comment: You can reference variables by their position in the variable list part of the SELECT statement in the GROUP BY or ORDER BY clause.  Saves a lot of re-typing.